# iOS UITableView move Cells in Code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I recently started working on a small `iOS` Project where I have a Game Score Leaderboard represented by a `UITableView`, whenever the Player gets a new Highscore the Leaderboard gets visible and his Score Entry (Including Picture, Name and Score) represented by a `UITableViewCell` is supposed to move to the new right Spot in the `TableView` Leaderboard it now belongs to. The calculation of the new `index` is working fine but the `cell` is not moving at all.

Some info:

- The Leaderboard is populated succesful,
- I set the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` to true
- Also implemented the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)`

correctly.

I am thinking that maybe I am missing something but the problem could also lie somewhere else, I don't know and would really appreciate some help.

Delegate Mehods for Editing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
// Handles reordering of Cells
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let player = players[sourceIndexPath.row]
    players.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    players.insert(player, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Code where I try to move Row

```
func newHighscore(highscore: Int) {
    friendsTableView.reloadData()
    let myNewIndex = Player.recalculateMyIndex(players: players, score: highscore)
    friendsTableView.moveRow(at: [0,Player.myIndex], to: [0,myNewIndex])

}
```

Comment: After you update your new data source for example the array of objects that have the score , name etc and you have placed your new score to the right place on the data source you should call the method self.myTableViewName.reloadData() and it will redraw the tableview

Comment: Use insertRow to move cells around

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. Will it then Animate this movement like it would when dragged in editing mode?

Comment: @Cesare but that inserts cells which I don’t Wanna do, I want to move them what else should the move at: to: function be about when its not moving rows from A to B

Comment: It's so hard, maybe better to use array's updating and after that use reloadData() ???

Comment: Why should it be hard?

Comment: update array and reload data more easlier

Comment: @SergeyHleb but then it’s much harder to show an animation where the cell moves up and all others move down

Comment: if you want to animate this, yes, you need to use this methods

Comment: Okay I need to use the move at:,to: method but what is supposed to be so hard about it, I used it as described in the Dev Reference but it is not working are there any special optional delegate functions I need to implement anything I need to call before the move function,...

Comment: add chunk of your code with this delegates methods to your question

Comment: and code where you implement new cell with score and tries to move it

Comment: Alright just did that, I am glad for your help @SergeyHleb

Comment: before your newHighscore() you doing update of array. and new highscore appears in it at last position?

Comment: Do you mean reloadData, yes I did this to show the updated data instantly, this function is used to reload the whole tree which I dont need, i just need to change one rows position

Comment: I write code for you yet, in few minutes answer can be

Comment: Thanks a lot @SergeyHleb

Comment: add it. insert it in new project, build and check. if you press button, cell moves to new position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works, but it only example. adapt it for you. create new file and put this code in it, build it and check.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var scores = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func move(from: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.tableView.moveRow(at: from, to: to)
        }) { (true) in
            // write here code to remove score from array at position "at" and insert at position "to" and after reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fromIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)
        let toIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        move(from: fromIndexPath, to: toIndexPath)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return scores.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TableViewCell
        if let cell = cell {
            cell.setText(text: scores[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

For correctly use, you need to insert new element in array at last, reload data and after you can call method move() and put in it current indexPath and indexPath to insert you need.

Comment: Okay when I now tried to use your example on my Project it didnt work, even I did not miss anything which means I added something that prevents it from happening

Comment: did you delete delegate methods, which don't used in my example? i can describe all steps if you need

Comment: Okay I finally figured it out, I don’t know why but when I call the UITableView.reloadData() shortly before the move function it does not work that was the problem

Comment: Okay this was just one of a few problems My View Controller a Child Controller of a Page View Controller and whenever I setViewController I call the move Table View Function you Write which does not work in this specific case. Any Ideas? Thanks so far though helped a lot already

Comment: It works though if I call it via Button Action so if you would write all the steps down it would not help since your code works

Comment: i don't see your code, and it's problem. are you have a telegram account?

Comment: Yes we should transfer the communication to Telegram

Comment: write to me how can I find you

Comment: My username is: TheRealSirJoe

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for move row Up/Down

```
var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:#selector(self.longPressGestureRecognized(_:)))                 
ToDoTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

//MARK: -longPressGestureRecognized

```
 func longPressGestureRecognized(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let longPress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    let state = longPress.state
    let locationInView = longPress.location(in: ToDoTableView)
    let indexPath = ToDoTableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)

    struct Path {
        static var initialIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil
    }

    switch state {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        if indexPath != nil {
            let cell = ToDoTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                cell?.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                        cell?.alpha = 1
                    })
                } else {
                    cell?.isHidden = true
                }
            })
        }
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:

        if ((indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != Path.initialIndexPath)) {
            itemsArray.insert(itemsArray.remove(at: Path.initialIndexPath!.row), at: indexPath!.row)
            ToDoTableView.moveRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!, to: indexPath!)
            Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    default:
        print("default:")
    }
}
```

Comment: But I dont need a gesture recognizer I want the cell to be animated automatically and not like in Edit Mode by the user itself as I understood this is simple done by the move function I dont understand why I should overcomplicate things when Apple already provides the methods I need. Can please somebody help me out?

Comment: Try this code https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/reorderable-cells/

Comment: this code is really nice when reorder by user is needed